# In App Purchase - Authenticating Old Test User

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, in-app-purchase

So I thought I had in-app purchase working, but my app sometimes triggers a popup user authentication action sheet with an old test user autopopulated in the action sheet. I've been creating test users with a sequential number, just because that's easy, and I can keep track of how old the users are. My current test user is #4. New test users were generally created because the old users were invalidated somehow.

Anyway, I sometimes get the popup screen for testuser #1 still (as well as #3). I figure that's because the transaction being looked at was originally dealt with using that user. But shouldn't these popups stop after the transaction is finalized using finishTransaction:?

What should I be checking? I assume I must have left something in limbo somewhere even though the products with downloads have been downloaded and all the products that were bought were finished (albeit with a different user since the original one was invalidated).

Answer (score 0):

I guess what must be happening is that unfinished transactions remain on the Apple server. I can't finish the transactions because the test users used were invalidated by accidental use in production. I will try deleting those users on the theory that deleting the users will also delete the pending transactions.

Comment: Nope. I'm still getting authentication messages for these. I have no idea how to make them go away now.